# MYSQL - How to create a variable inside stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I'm trying to make a stored procedure that conditionally if the document number exists looks for an invoice and updates its balance to a new value that is a subtraction of the current balance and an input value, but for some reason when the procedure is executed it doesn't the update is running.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_egreso(IN no_registro VARCHAR(255), IN id_proveedor  INT, IN descripcion VARCHAR(255), IN no_doc VARCHAR(255),IN total DECIMAL ,IN no_cuenta VARCHAR(100),IN aprobado VARCHAR(255),IN subclase_gasto VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
     IF no_doc!='' AND no_doc IS NOT NULL THEN
        
         UPDATE ct_facturas SET saldo_fact =((SELECT saldo_fact FROM ct_facturas WHERE no_registro = no_doc)-total) WHERE no_registro = no_doc;
    END IF;
    SET total = ABS(total);
    INSERT INTO ct_regtransac(no_registro,no_cuenta,vr_transaccion,tipo_mov,saldoreg) VALUES (no_registro,no_cuenta,total,1,total*-1);
    INSERT INTO ct_egresos(tipo_reg,no_registro,id_proveedor,descripcion,no_doc,total,no_cuenta,aprobado, tipo_movimiento_cta, subclase_gasto, estado) VALUES ('EGRESO',no_registro,id_proveedor,descripcion,no_doc,total,no_cuenta,aprobado,'Salida',subclase_gasto,NULL);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

the queries inside if are not executing but i executed that update into phpMyAdmin with the same parameters and did work ,could it be that the if is not correctly written or the update sentence is confusing parameters?

Comment: make sure your variables don't have the same name as a column

Comment: looks like your subselect is finding the same record you are updating?  there's no reason to do that; just `set saldo_fact=saldo_fact - total`